# Why is my date in python wrong after formating using timedelta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, timedelta

I am using Django and have a problem with a date that I need to calculate.
The Variable data > test should be 17:00 and not 15:00. Why does this happen as soon as I format the date?

My timezone is Europe/Berlin. Changing the timezone has to effect to the time printing in test. It is always -2h

```
def date(req):
    now = timezone.now()
    model = MyModel.objects.filter(date__gt=now).first()
    next = model.date
    future = timezone.timedelta(hours=float(model.future)) #model.future = 1.5
    open = next-future
    date = next.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    data = {
        'next': next,
        'date': date,
        'time': open.astimezone(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
        'test': open.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S%z')
    }
```

What I get:

```
next: 20. November 2021 18:30
date: 2021/11/20
time: 2021-11-20 15:15:00.000000
test: 2021/11/20 15:00:00+0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
from django.utils import timezone

def date(req):
    now = timezone.now()
    model = MyModel.objects.filter(date__gt=now).first()
    next = model.date
    future = timezone.timedelta(hours=float(model.future)) #model.future = 1.5
    open = next-future
    date = timezone.localtime(open)
    data = {
        'next': date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'),
        'date': date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),
        'time': date.strftime('%H:%M:%S'),
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

You should use:

```
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now()
```

Datetime isn't time-zone aware.

Comment: This is not solving my problem. I changed now variable as you mentioned but the result is the same.

Comment: So is `now` using the correct timezone and `future` is not? Or both are not the correct tz?

Comment: idk - the time I expected is 20. November 17:00 (see `time`) so `future` should be also correct i think.

Answer (score 0):

You cut the timezone info (the offset +02:00) with .strftime(). You need to include it with %z.

In case you want to convert it to a time string with the offset already added.

open.astimezone(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

Comment: I add the `%z` but same. The date I import over an api is like this: `2022-05-05T11:30:00.000Z`. I updated my answer.